# How to combine string subtypes in Python like bf"Hello, {name}!"

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

How to combine string subtypes in Python 3? Under subtypes I mean f-strings, b-string, r-string, u-string... Is there a way to use both f and b string to insert variables with `{}` into binary string?
I tried to use `fb"Hello, {name}"` and `bf"Hello, {name}"`, but nothing worked and `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` raises.

Comment: This can be found in the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: @SimonFink answers for many stackoverflow questions you can find in official docs. For example, how to delete last element of list, and so on

Comment: Sure, so why should somebody take the effort and explain it, if the documentation exists and is very clear and specific about the question asked? If something is unclear with the documentation, you'll need to re-formulate your question.

Comment: @Simon Fink You're right.